# Cisco Prime NCS not starting

Tags: networking, cisco, network-monitoring

I have received the Cisco Prime OVA file and which we placed onto an Oracle virtual environment. We turn the VM on and the CLI boots, When we try to start the NCS service we get errors.

```
HOSTNAME/USER# ncs start

Starting Network Control System...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.isPhysicalAppliance(UDIManager.java:184)
        at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.start(WCSAdmin.java:335)
        at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.runMain(WCSAdmin.java:281)
        at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.main(WCSAdmin.java:901)
```

Logs

```
HOSTNAME/USER# show logging   
    07/18/13 10:25:38.878 INFO  [system] [main] Setting management interface address to 192.168.0.10
    07/18/13 10:25:38.884 INFO  [system] [main] Setting peer server interface address to 192.168.0.10
    07/18/13 10:25:38.884 INFO  [system] [main] Setting client interface address to 192.168.0.10
    07/18/13 10:25:38.884 INFO  [system] [main] Setting local host name to HOSTNAME
    07/18/13 10:25:40.341 ERROR [system] [main] THROW
    java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
            at com.cisco.server.persistence.util.OracleSchemaUtil.openConnection(OracleSchemaUtil.java:277)
            at com.cisco.server.persistence.util.OracleSchemaUtil.dbServerUp(OracleSchemaUtil.java:836)
            at com.cisco.packaging.DBAdmin.dbServerUp(DBAdmin.java:1429)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.status(WCSAdmin.java:833)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.status(WCSAdmin.java:757)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.wcsServerUp(WCSAdmin.java:637)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.start(WCSAdmin.java:294)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.runMain(WCSAdmin.java:281)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.main(WCSAdmin.java:901)
    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
            at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:375)
            at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:422)
            at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:678)
            at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:238)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308)
            ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
            at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:209)
            at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:123)
            at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:353)
            ... 20 more
    07/18/13 10:25:40.347 INFO  [admin] [main]
    07/18/13 10:25:40.347 INFO  [admin] [main] Starting Network Control System...
    07/18/13 10:25:40.347 INFO  [admin] [main]
    07/18/13 10:25:40.394 ERROR [admin] [main] Problem using CARS API:
    com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException: CARS_FAILURE : -999 : Failed to get UDI configuration. : Failure occurred during request
            at com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException.analyzeReturnCode(CARSException.java:118)
            at com.cisco.cars.serviceEngine.impl.EngineAdminServiceImpl.getUDI(EngineAdminServiceImpl.java:66)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.generateUDI(UDIManager.java:69)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.setPersistenceDirectory(UDIManager.java:139)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.start(WCSAdmin.java:332)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.runMain(WCSAdmin.java:281)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.main(WCSAdmin.java:901)
    07/18/13 10:25:40.396 ERROR [admin] [main] Problem using CARS API:
    com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException: CARS_FAILURE : -999 : Failed to get UDI configuration. : Failure occurred during request
            at com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException.analyzeReturnCode(CARSException.java:118)
            at com.cisco.cars.serviceEngine.impl.EngineAdminServiceImpl.getUDI(EngineAdminServiceImpl.java:66)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.generateUDI(UDIManager.java:69)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.setVirtualPID(UDIManager.java:169)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.start(WCSAdmin.java:333)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.runMain(WCSAdmin.java:281)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.main(WCSAdmin.java:901)
    07/18/13 10:25:40.397 ERROR [admin] [main] Problem using CARS API:
    com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException: CARS_FAILURE : -999 : Failed to get UDI configuration. : Failure occurred during request
            at com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException.analyzeReturnCode(CARSException.java:118)
            at com.cisco.cars.serviceEngine.impl.EngineAdminServiceImpl.getUDI(EngineAdminServiceImpl.java:66)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.generateUDI(UDIManager.java:69)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.setPhysicalPID(UDIManager.java:154)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.start(WCSAdmin.java:334)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.runMain(WCSAdmin.java:281)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.main(WCSAdmin.java:901)
    07/18/13 10:25:40.397 ERROR [admin] [main] Problem using CARS API:
    com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException: CARS_FAILURE : -999 : Failed to get UDI configuration. : Failure occurred during request
            at com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException.analyzeReturnCode(CARSException.java:118)
            at com.cisco.cars.serviceEngine.impl.EngineAdminServiceImpl.getUDI(EngineAdminServiceImpl.java:66)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.generateUDI(UDIManager.java:69)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.getUDI(UDIManager.java:112)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.isPhysicalAppliance(UDIManager.java:184)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.start(WCSAdmin.java:335)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.runMain(WCSAdmin.java:281)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.main(WCSAdmin.java:901)
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is usually caused by starting the prime vm on a hypervisor other than vmware.  I tried this too, HPG6 using virtualbox, same problem.

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. We are not a discussion forum; please make sure your answers remain focused on _answering_ the question.